# how to detect scrollHeight from div when scroll height change every time?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, scroll

I am creating chat program in php using jquery, ajax and MySQL.
and my problem how to auto scroll down when div is overflowed.

like when user enter new line it will goes down and I want to auto scroll down when new messages appeares down.

and I am trying to do this dynamically using scroll height change to trigger this `$('.main').stop().animate({scrollTop:$('.main')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);`. because using scroll height changing it will also scroll to other users browser who is chatting on the other side.

I also have tried to trigger scroll down event using `keypress` and `click` event but that is only works for the current users browser, so on the other hand for another user that wont work or wont auto scroll down, he have to scroll manually to view new messages and I don't want that.

so that's why I am trying to use scroll height event. I also tried the [mutate](http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/) plugin for this purpose and it works fine only for the localhost and conflict on the live server and super slow down the chat.

So I have to leave this plugin for this problem.

so please kindly give me the solution without using any plugin to achieve this purpose.

I have created something like this

```
setInterval(function(){
    oldsH = 0;
    newsH = msgBox.prop('scrollHeight');
    if (newsH > oldsH){
    oldsH = newsH
       msgBox.stop().animate({scrollTop:(msgBox[0].scrollHeight)},1000);
    }
},500);
```

and it only works in `setInterval()` function, I don't want to use it in this function.
because it triggers again and again the scroll event,which cause you can't scroll up to see older messages.

so is there anyway to achieve this without setInterval??

many thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

Comment: Probably you can achieve this with using [Window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one chat box, then instead of a class, assign it an id and use code like below:

```
var chatBox = $('#chatBox');
chatBox.scrollTop(chatBox[0].scrollHeight);
```

For your reference, I created a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4Mwz/6/)**

Comment: well let me check it and than let you know.

Comment: I don't want to use it under setInterval, because using under this you can't scroll up to see older msgs.

Comment: and I have 2 msg boxes, 1 for admin and 2nd for users

Comment: I gave an example using setInterval() just to populate the chat boxes (because I cant be sitting around doing chat stuff). You need to change this script as per your needs.

Comment: I tried, but its not worthy, I already tried this method too, but its doesn't suit for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be glad to know if you already solved your problem since this is a two-years-ago question.

I've been searching for the function similar to yours for a chat-application for my client. And I solved the problem by myself alternately (Since the internet's resource is limited).

According to you, auto scroll-down when new messages received would be annoying to user when he is reading the old messages. So, you can actually prompt the user if there's new message received and provide a button to scroll down to latest message.

This is how I solved my problem, perhaps yours too :)

```
   // Scroll-to-latest toggle
   $(document).ready(function(){   
           $(BUTTON_DIV).click(function()
         {       
               var latest = $('CONTENT_DIV');
             latest.scrollTop(latest[0].scrollHeight);
           });
     });

   // Prompt with "Scroll-to-latest toggle" if new message detected by scrollheight change
    function customFunc(){  
     var window = $("CONTENT_DIV");
     var scroll = $("BUTTON_DIV");

     if(window.scrollTop() + window.innerHeight() >= window[0].scrollHeight) {
       scroll.hide(); //hide scroll-to-latest toggle
     } else {
       scroll.show(); //show s-t-l toggle
     }
  }
    setInterval (customFunc, UR_INTERVAL); //detect per one ms
```

Full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Jvloo/k962u211/